# How to scan a text file and input the characters into an Array?

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

I am trying to scan a text file and input the characters into an array.

```
char newArray[500];

FILE *fp2;
fp2 = fopen("LeftPattern_Color.txt", "r");

char ch;

while ((ch = fgetc(fp2)) != EOF)
    {
        int i = 0;  
        newArray[i] = ch;
        i++;
    }

fclose(fp2);
```

But when I printed out the characters to test if the inputted characters are in `newArray[500]`, there was nothing printed.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
{
  printf("%c", newArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: `fgetc()` returns an `int`, so `ch` should be of type `int` and make sure to print the exact number of characters you read, otherwise you will print garbage.

Comment: move `int i = 0;` outside the while loop

Comment: why are you not using `fread` ?

Comment: @bruno I'm still new, so I didn't know about it till now :D

Comment: @AndyWu look at my answer

Comment: @AndyWu I edited my answer to put two proposals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as said in remarks you need to use an `int` for *ch* to be able to compare with `EOF`, and `int i = 0;` must be outside of the `for` else you always write in `newArray[0]`

Note also you write all the 500 elements of the array, even you correct your code you will print non initialized elements in case the file has less than 500 characters, you need to write only the element from 0 up to *i* non included

Anyway you can just use `fread`

```
size_n nread = fread(newArray, 1, sizeof(newArray), fp2);
```

and to print you can use `fwrite` :

```
fwrite(newArray, 1, nread, stdout);
```

I also encourage you to check *fp2* is not NULL to detect the case you cannot open your file

---

A corrected version from your code can be :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *fp2 = fopen("LeftPattern_Color.txt", "r");

  if (fp2 == NULL)
    perror("cannot read LeftPattern_Color.txt");
  else {
    char newArray[500];
    int ch;
    int i = 0;  

    while ((ch = fgetc(fp2)) != EOF)
        newArray[i++] = ch;

    fclose(fp2);

    for(int i2 = 0; i2 < i; i2++)
      printf("%c", newArray[i2]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and executions :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall f.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
cannot read LeftPattern_Color.txt: No such file or directory
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ (date ; pwd) > LeftPattern_Color.txt
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
dimanche 17 mai 2020, 11:37:47 (UTC+0200)
/tmp
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

---

A shorter version can be :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *fp2 = fopen("LeftPattern_Color.txt", "r");

  if (fp2 == NULL)
    perror("cannot read LeftPattern_Color.txt");
  else {
    char newArray[500];
    size_t nread = fread(newArray, 1, sizeof(newArray), fp2);

    fclose(fp2);
    fwrite(newArray, 1, nread, stdout);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and xexcutions:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall ff.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ rm LeftPattern_Color.txt
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
cannot read LeftPattern_Color.txt: No such file or directory
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ (date ; pwd) > LeftPattern_Color.txt
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
dimanche 17 mai 2020, 11:41:19 (UTC+0200)
/tmp
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: @AndyWu you welcome. Note I used `fwrite` to be symmetric with `fread`, but in that case you can also use `write`